# ViewControllers of Cocoa library views

Tags: cocoa-touch, model-view-controller, uitextfield, uitextview

I am developing a gesture keyboard for iOS. I want it to be a self-contained component to just set as the inputView of any UITextView or UITextField.

Now, I am having trouble wrapping my head around the design of cocoa library objects. In order to adhere to the MVC-pattern I have put the gesture and dictionary logic into Controller objects. I'm fine with these being singletons or instances created by the user and set as delegates or properties of the view.

But some of the logic belongs in a ViewController. How is the logic of complex views such as UITextView actually implemented for library objects? Does the view load the controller, I feel queezy about that..

Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: To clarify: this is strictly a design question. I am not looking for library ViewControllers to extend or categorize, just wondering how the logic is organized for Apple's complex views.